# Is PowerBI available with SQL Server 2016(Standard OR Enterprise) edition

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Please help me in understand that,

- Is PowerBI part of SQL Server 2016(Standard OR Enterprise) edition or PowerBI is separate setup that needs to installed for reports?

Best Regards,
Arayn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI is a separate package and is not included in the MS SQL Server Package. But SSRS comes along with SQL Server Installer package. you can also use that for creating reports. otherwise, download Power BI from the [Official Website](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/get-started/)

Comment: As per this link "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/05/03/introducing-power-bi-report-server-for-on-premises-power-bi-report-publishing/" we can purchase either Power BI Premium or SQL Server EE+SA if the organization would like to run Power BI Report Server.

Comment: the link is broken. please check

Comment: @Arayn. they are separate packages. and you can download Power BI for free. no need of purchase

Comment: apologies, updated link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/05/03/introducing-power-bi-report-server-for-on-premises-power-bi-report-publishing/

Comment: it is about the report deployment. Power BI Is built on the same Platform of SSRS. And this article specifies the rights that a premium power BI user will get to deploy the reports on Cloud. These premium features are also available with SQL Server EE or above

Answer (score 0):

This depends on clarification of your question but to summarise the full "suite" if you will..

Power BI itself is a cloud platform as a service.

FREE - You can create Power BI reports & datasets using Power BI Desktop & these can be deployed to the Power BI Service.

There are then 2 paid models. ([Pricing](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/))

- Per User per Month fee of $9.99
- Power BI Premium (This can be obtained 3 ways)

  - Based on [capacity](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/calculator/)
  - Part of the SQL Server Enterprise **+ Software Assurance**
  - Part of an Office 365 Subscription.

[Here's a good summary of purchasing Power BI Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-premium-purchase) from @Guyinacube

With Power BI Premium you can install the [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/)

This is a separate installer from SQL Server as is Reporting Services (2016 & 2017).

It behaves and looks very similar to Reporting Services but is a separate install/interface & database

[Here is a great reference page for ALL things Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/)

Comment: Does Power BI Report Server require SQL Server Enterprise Edition, or will it still function with Standard?

Comment: @AsherRankin there's no technical requirements for SQL server version, similar to SSRS. it's only a licensing restriction.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there who is trying to get this to work: having SQL Server Enterprise + Software Assurance does **NOT** grant you the free license that you require. You'll still need to purchase what is called "Power BI Pro" licenses for any report authors that will be publishing Power BI reports. To put simply, you'll have "free" environment to publish reports but no license to publish anything.... in case you decide to PAY for the license, on top of your Enterprise + SA, [here is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-purchasing-power-bi-pro).